# What is a spectrogram and how do I set its parameters?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, spectrogram

I am trying to plot the spectrogram of my time domain signal given:

```
N=5000;
phi = (rand(1,N)-0.5)*pi;
a = tan((0.5.*phi));
i = 2.*a./(1-a.^2);
plot(i);
spectrogram(i,100,1,100,1e3);
```

The problem is I don't understand the parameters and what values should be given. These values that I am using, I referred to MATLAB's online documentation of `spectrogram`.  I am new to MATLAB, and I am just not getting the idea.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked the help? http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html;jsessionid=204fc52302b5fd3f2f47972b67b1

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Before we actually go into what that MATLAB command does, you probably want to know what a spectrogram is.  That way you'll get more meaning into how each parameter works.

A spectrogram is a visual representation of the [Short-Time Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform).  Think of this as taking chunks of an input signal and applying a local Fourier Transform on each chunk.  Each chunk has a specified width and you apply a Fourier Transform to this chunk.  You should take note that each chunk has an associated frequency distribution.  For each chunk that is centred at a specific time point in your time signal, you get a bunch of frequency components.  The collection of all of these frequency components at each chunk and plotted all together is what is essentially a spectrogram.

The spectrogram is a 2D visual heat map where the horizontal axis represents the time of the signal and the vertical axis represents the frequency axis.  What is visualized is an image where darker colours means that for a particular time point and a particular frequency, the lower in magnitude the frequency component is, the darker the colour.  Similarly, the higher in magnitude the frequency component is, the lighter the colour.

Here's one perfect example of a spectrogram:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram)</sup>

Therefore, for each time point, we see a distribution of frequency components.  Think of each column as the frequency decomposition of a chunk centred at this time point.  For each column, we see a varying spectrum of colours.  The darker the colour is, the lower the magnitude component at that frequency is and vice-versa.

---

So!... now you're armed with that, let's go into how MATLAB works in terms of the function and its parameters.  The way you are calling [`spectrogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) conforms to this version of the function:

```
spectrogram(x,window,noverlap,nfft,fs)
```

Let's go through each parameter one by one so you can get a greater understanding of what each does:

- `x` - This is the input time-domain signal you wish to find the spectrogram of.  It can't get much simpler than that.  In your case, the signal you want to find the spectrogram of is defined in the following code:

  ```
  N=5000;
  phi = (rand(1,N)-0.5)*pi;
  a = tan((0.5.*phi));
  i = 2.*a./(1-a.^2);
  ```

  Here, `i` is the signal you want to find the spectrogram of.
- `window` - If you recall, we decompose the image into chunks, and each chunk has a specified width.  `window` defines the width of each chunk in terms of **samples**.  As this is a discrete-time signal, you know that this signal was sampled with a particular sampling frequency and sampling period.  You can determine how large the window is in terms of samples by:

  `window_samples = window_time/Ts`

  `Ts` is the sampling time of your signal.  Setting the window size is actually very empirical and requires a lot of experimentation.  Basically, the larger the window size, the better frequency resolution you get as you're capturing more of the frequencies, but the time localization is poor.  Similarly, the smaller the window size, the better localization you have in time, but you don't get that great of a frequency decomposition.  I don't have any suggestions here on what the most optimal size is... which is why [wavelets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet) are preferred when it comes to time-frequency decomposition.  For each "chunk", the chunks get decomposed into smaller chunks of a dynamic width so you get a mixture of good time and frequency localization.
- `noverlap` - Another way to ensure good frequency localization is that the chunks are **overlapping**.  A proper spectrogram ensures that each chunk has a certain number of samples that are overlapping for each chunk and `noverlap` defines how many samples are overlapped in each window.  The default is 50% of the width of each chunk.
- `nfft` - You are essentially taking the FFT of each chunk.  `nfft` tells you how many FFT points are desired to be computed per chunk.  The default number of points is the largest of either 256, or `floor(log2(N))` where `N` is the length of the signal.   `nfft` also gives a measure of how fine-grained the frequency resolution will be. A higher number of FFT points would give higher frequency resolution and thus showing fine-grained details along the frequency axis of the spectrogram if visualised.
- `fs` - The sampling frequency of your signal.  The default is 1 Hz, but you can override this to whatever the sampling frequency your signal is at.

---

Therefore, what you should probably take out of this is that I can't really tell you how to set the parameters.  It all depends on what signal you have, but hopefully the above explanation will give you a better idea of **how** to set the parameters.

---

Good luck!

Comment: This is a great answer. I would just add that `nfft` gives a measure of how fine-grained the frequency resolution will be. Higher number of FFT points would give higher frequency resolution, showing fine-grained details along the frequency axis of the spectrogram if visualised.

Comment: @AruniRC That is very true. I'll put that in. Thanks!

Comment: "Darker" color mean black color or high density shade of any color?

Comment: @Man Darker as in a darker shade. The point is that you don't need it to be this way. So long as the colour map is consistent. You could have brighter colours map to small values and dull colours map to large values. It just so happens that the above example does it the former way. You just need to be consistent with the assignment of colours and depending on what framework you use, there are several options for colour maps you can use for visualisation.

Comment: You mean dull and dark to be synonym keeping in view your comment and answer?

Comment: @Man yes. Why does this matter so much?

Comment: No issues . Thanks

Comment: Great answer! I'd just like to point out that the NFFT parameter in fact equals 256 or `2^ceil(log2(N))`, not `floor(...)`.  (The actual calculations in `signal/signal/private/welchparse.m` are a bit more convoluted than that, but that's not important.)